# Django Save and add another behaviour modification

Tags: python, django

In my django admin console i would that after user press "Save and add another" button the fields value of the form remain populate with last values inserted but i don't know if and how this could be possible.
Someone could help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following should help you:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        latest_object = MyModel.objects.latest('created_at')   # change this field to fit your model

        form.base_fields['my_first_field_name'].initial = latest_object.my_first_field_name
        form.base_fields['my_second_field_name'].initial = latest_object.my_second_field_name

        return form
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, i have to add the code in my admin.py file? i have to import something? many thanks

Comment: @ManuelSanti yes, in admin.py. Import your model and change the code as needed

Answer (score 1):

You can add the option `save_as = True` inside the `ModelAdmin` you want to use ([here is the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_as))

This will change the button 'Save and add another' to 'Save as new' only for the existent objects, or the object you've just created after using the button 'Save and continue editing'.

This allow to use any created object to create a variant.

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
```

Comment: Where i have to insert the code? in admin.py? i have to import something? thanks

Comment: @ManuelSanti in the model you need, inside admin.py (the class will be something like `YourModelAdmin`)